# Clean previous JQuery validation error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two validations for the same field and I´m using jQuery Validator, I would like to know how to clean the previous error message generated.

My problem now is that If I have the error for empty field, never is removed if I have another error like value must be higher than 10. I still showing "field must not be empty" when the value is 7.

I google on that and all suggestion are resetForm of validation.

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate(

);

validator.resetForm();
```

But of course if I do that the error message wont be showed. I just need to clean the previous error from the DOM before check for news.

Anyone knows another approach directly interacting with the DOM?

I´m trying this without success.

```
if ($.validator.defaults.onfocusout) {
    $(element).unbind(".validate-biggerThanOrigin").bind("blur.validate-biggerThanOrigin", function () {
        $(element).valid();
    });
}
```

We´re defining the validation like this.

```
     $.validator.addMethod("biggerThanOrigin", function (value, element, param) {
            return biggerThanOrigin(value, element, param, validationMessages.biggerThanOrigin, validationMessages.referenceForkEmpty);
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("lessThanOrigin", function (value, element, param) {
            return lessThanOrigin(value, element, param, validationMessages.lessThanOrigin, validationMessages.referenceForkEmpty);
        });
```

Regards.

Comment: $window.location.reload();

Comment: reaload the whole page it´s not an option. Actually it´s a dialog

Comment: reload the whole thing in dialog box using EndRequestHandler/BeginRequestHandler

Answer (score 1):

You should provide separate validation messages for errors.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
     "required": true,
     "minlength": 10
  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "Please specify your name",
      minlength: "Your name must be atleast 10 characters long"
    }
  }
});
```

This should work in your case.

EDIT:

Here is a working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLynmqaL/)**.

Comment: we have separate message, that´s not the problem.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle?

Comment: My structure it´s not quite the same. We´re adding into the $.validator all validations when we initialize our validator.js

Comment: So do you have separate messages for these methods?

Answer (score 0):

As you asked another approach , so here is the solution.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q45eychu/):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) 
      $('label').text('Field must not be empty');
  else if ($(this).val() <= 10) 
      $('label').text('Value must be greater than 10');
  else 
      $('label').text('');
});
```

This is just an example. You can use the approach. 
Thanks anyway !

Comment: You can use answer number 1. Its well tested method to clear your error message